# Watchguard - Configure custom domain IP resolve

Tags: watchguard

A Watchguard firewall device used as DHCP server in a Local LAN office network.
There is an internal web server pc connected within the same LAN.

Lets say the website hosted in the web server accessible by entering this IP on any browser:

http://192.168.1.2:28762

Everything works fine.

But the users always can't remember the IP + Port.

So, is there a way to configure it as simple as this:

http://MyServer

then the watchguard will translate it into: http://192.168.1.2:28762

Which section should I look for in the configuration of Watchguard?
What is the terms that I should continue to search in Google?

Thanks for your sharing.

Comment: Well, why can't you host the site on 80/443? That will solve your problem. If that's not possible, you can configure a reverse proxy on the web host to proxy requests to 80/443 to your proper application port.

Comment: @EEAA I have many websites for different admin purposes. around 9 websites with same IP but different ports. More websites are coming in future.

Comment: A reverse proxy with name-based host routing is the answer then. This is not a function that can or should be handled by your router